# UItableView deplicated cell when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

Sorry for posting this question again but I've looked into many answers and neither of them was helpfull to solve my issue.

So this my code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"radioCell";

RadioTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[RadioTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

[self configureCommentCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];



return cell;
}
```

when I scroll down my cell get mixed up and some of data are repeated, so I've tried this :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"memberCell";
RadioCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RadioTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

and this :

```
    RadioTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RadioTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }
```

But it didn't fixed my issue and I get white empty cells ? please how to fix this issue ?

**Update**

```
- (void)configureCommentCell:(RadioTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *object;
if ([_dataArray[indexPath.section] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    object = [_dataArray[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
    object = [[_dataArray[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"radioList"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (object[@"jsonUrl"]) {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:object[@"jsonUrl"] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        //NSDictionary *tempObject = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
        if (![[responseObject objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"error"]) {
            NSDictionary *tempObject = [responseObject[@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.playingNow.text = tempObject[@"song"];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}

cell.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", object[@"title"]];
if (object[@"logoUrl"])
    [cell.logo setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object[@"logoUrl"]]];
}
```

Comment: May you please add your method cellforrow..?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma any update here?

Answer (score 1):

I see that your problem is that you are fetching the data of you cells inside `configureCommentCell` that's called inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. which is wrong, because it too late to fetch data inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, in this delegate method you should return the cell.

**this line may be called before retrieving the data from server :**

```
cell.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", object[@"title"]];
```

**Instead  you should:**

1. Fetch the data inside a separate method for example `fetchData`
2. when the data is downloaded inside the completion block of `AFNetworking` method, store the data inside an `NSArray` called for example `myDataArray` still inside the completion block call `[self.tableView reloadData];`
3. In viewDidLoad method just call your method  `fetchData`

   And your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should looks like this:

   ```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

         // hey please give me the cell to display ... harry up please
         // please harry up ! oh my god  you are fetching data from server 
         // while I am asking for the cell ! 
         // ok I don't care do what you want 
         // I will return an empty cell anyway
         // and guess what I will not take in consideration
         // the retried data  because it's inside a block 
         // which is called asynchronously


         static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"radioCell";

         RadioTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];    if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[RadioTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];    }

    // now before return the cell you need to update the content of cell    
    // maybe you have an array of items and you should update the label        
    // for example here and then return the cell

       cell.usernameLabel = self.myDataArray[indexPath.row]; // example


       return cell; 
   }
   ```

Comment: I've tried this allready and it give same result empty white cell

Comment: No that's wrong the configure cell hase no effect on code it's just way to make your code much clean. Also moving the code from configureCell to the `cellForRow` will not change the result .

Comment: @Chlebta did you read my answer ? actually I didn't tell you to move the code to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` actually your problem is that you are fetching the data inside that method, please read again my answer, I am sure about the cause of the issue

Comment: @Chlebta in all my projects I am using `AFNetworking` . By the way read my updated answer (the comments in code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83442/discussion-between-aladin-and-chlebta).

Answer (score 0):

Well the TableView is reusing the cells, and you add the image every time a cell is displaid. Thus when reusing the cell you add an other image, but there already is an image.

You will have to reuse the image view, and only add the image if you create the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifer = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifer]autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;   


        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,0,30,44)];
        imageView.tag = 1001;
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release], imageView= nil;
    }

    TabBarTestAppDelegate *delegate = (TabBarTestAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray *local = delegate.myData;
    // ok, it's horrible, don't look at it   :-)
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"       " ,[local objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //

    NSString* name = nil;;
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        name = @"topicon";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row + 1 == [local count]) {
        name = @"bottomicon";
    }
    else {
        name = @"innericon";
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png"]];

    return cell;
 }
```